# how to generate new columns using double loops for rows and columns in r

Tags: r, function, loops

I am creating a table of projections for 10 years basis my data test_dat.

```
dput(test_dat)
structure(list(hirepct = c(0, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0329218106995885, 
1.92592592592593, 0.670212765957447), prompct = c(NA, 0, 0.00823045267489712, 
2.2962962962963, 0.0500483558994197), exitpct = c(0, 0.0555555555555556, 
0.0507544581618656, 1.80246913580247, 0.703094777562863), grpcount = c(7, 
36, 729, 81, 4136), year1 = c(7, 42, 902, 298, 3793), year2 = c(7, 
49.4238683127572, 1570.21124828532, 524.623537383289, 3478.44511605416
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Every year the row values are generated basis a formula, i have generated the rows already for one column using the for loop:

To add columns for 10 years i am first creating names of columns as: year1,year2 and so on:

```
 namevector<-c(paste0("year",seq(1:10)))
```

Then i am creating column with NA values for 10 years:

```
 test_dat[,namevector]<-NA
```

now for year 1 i have created the  value for every row using the formula

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test_dat)-1){
  
  col1=test_dat[["grpcount"]][i]*(1+test_dat[["hirepct"]][i]-test_dat[["exitpct"]][i])+
    test_dat[["prompct"]][i+1]*test_dat[["grpcount"]][i+1] 
  test_dat$year1[i]<-col1
  
}
test_dat$year1[nrow(test_dat)]<-test_dat$grpcount[nrow(test_dat)]*(1+test_dat$hirepct[nrow(test_dat)]-
                                                     test_dat$exitpct[nrow(test_dat)]-
                                                     test_dat$prompct[nrow(test_dat)])
```

year 2 and so on are then calculated based on previous calculated columns, so every new column is using the earlier one. So I need to create another loop to get 10 columns.
year 2 column I am calculating them separately :

#year 2

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test_dat)-1){
  
  col1=test_dat[["year1"]][i]*(1+test_dat[["hirepct"]][i]-test_dat[["exitpct"]][i])+
    test_dat[["prompct"]][i+1]*test_dat[["year1"]][i+1]
  test_dat$year2[i]<-col1
  
}
test_dat$year2[nrow(test_dat)]<-test_dat$year1[nrow(test_dat)]*(1+test_dat$hirepct[nrow(test_dat)]-
                                                  test_dat$exitpct[nrow(test_dat)]-
                                                  test_dat$prompct[nrow(test_dat)])
```

I need a function to create these columns and rows for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try with a function rewrite your calculation logic in `dplyr` grammar

```r
library(dplyr)

column_1 <- paste0("year", seq(1, 10, by = 1))
column_2 <- c("grpcount", paste0("year", seq(1, 9, by = 1)))

# Column to calculate
column_1
#>  [1] "year1"  "year2"  "year3"  "year4"  "year5"  "year6"  "year7"  "year8" 
#>  [9] "year9"  "year10"

# Column that column_1 will be calculated based on in same order
column_2
#>  [1] "grpcount" "year1"    "year2"    "year3"    "year4"    "year5"   
#>  [7] "year6"    "year7"    "year8"    "year9"

# Calulate function
calculate_year_var <- function(column_1, column_2, data) {
  data %>%
    mutate(!!sym(column_1) := if_else(row_number() == nrow(test_dat),
      !!sym(column_2)  * (1 + hirepct - exitpct - prompct),
      !!sym(column_2)  * (1 + hirepct - exitpct) +
        lead(prompct, 1) * lead(!!sym(column_2), 1)))
}

# loop through column 1 and calculate and assign back to test_dat each loop
for (i in 1:length(column_1)) {
  test_dat <- calculate_year_var(column_1[i], column_2[i], test_dat)
}
```

**Final output**

```r
test_dat
#>      hirepct     prompct    exitpct grpcount year1     year2     year3    year4
#> 1 0.00000000          NA 0.00000000        7     7    7.0000    7.0000    7.000
#> 2 0.05555556 0.000000000 0.05555556       36    42   48.0000   54.0000   60.000
#> 3 0.03292181 0.008230453 0.05075446      729   902 1071.9150 1238.7999 1402.709
#> 4 1.92592593 2.296296296 1.80246914       81   298  541.7901  815.6778 1123.379
#> 5 0.67021277 0.050048356 0.70309478     4136  3793 3478.4451 3189.9764 2925.430
#>      year5    year6    year7    year8    year9   year10
#> 1    7.000    7.000    7.000    7.000    7.000    7.000
#> 2   66.000   72.000   78.000   84.000   90.000   96.000
#> 3 1563.695 1721.810 1877.106 2029.632 2179.438 2326.573
#> 4 1469.067 1857.434 2293.747 2783.925 3334.620 3953.301
#> 5 2682.823 2460.336 2256.299 2069.184 1897.585 1740.218
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I just checked it for data correctness, the solution is working but the data is correct only till year 1 after that it is not giving right values , couldn't find the reason yet

Comment: Found the source of error, it should be lead(!!sym(column2), 1) instead of lead(grpcount, 1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to vectorize your solution and use `for` only if you have no other choice. Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- test_dat$grpcount
for(i in namevector){
      test_dat <- test_dat %>% mutate(
            !!sym(i) :=a*(1+hirepct-exitpct)+
                  lead(prompct,default = last(prompct))*lead(a,default = -last(a)))
      a=test_dat[,i]}
```